# SQL 2 Columns of Different Types in Same Table - Working With 'Uknown' Amount

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, reporting, mariadb-10.4

I'm very new to SQL and I've been searching for an answer for a while now, can't seem to find it.

I have 1 table of CustOrders which has 3 columns.

#### Table CustOrders

- Name (varchar)
- Number_Orders (int)
- order_date (datetime)

## Question

I would like to get a list of customers that have had less orders than a specific customer 'x'. How would I go about doing that?

#### Select Statement

I tried with this logic, which didn't seem to work and is probably all wrong, which was:

```sql
SELECT name, number_orders
FROM custOrders
WHERE number_orders < (select number_orders from custOrders where name = 'x');
```

It returned an empty set, which should not be empty, because I know there are customers there with less orders.

Could you please help me with this?

I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM custOrders t1, custOrders t2 
WHERE t1.number_orders < t2.number_orders 
  AND t2.name = 'x';
```

PS. `custOrders.name` must be defined as unique by according index.

Comment: Hi Akina, thank you so much! This works now. Do you maybe know how to make it display only the names? Right now it displays the whole table. 
I tried with SELECT name, t1.* (got abiguous error), I tried t1.name, didn't work sitll displayed everything, tried custOrders.name, got a syntax error.
Thanks in advance and sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: @Banananas *how to make it display only the names?* Replace `SELECT t1.* FROM ...` with `SELECT t1.name FROM ...`.